# How to implement book view flipping like paper 53

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, opengl-es-2.0

I want to implement book view functionality same as in paper 53. It's like a book that opens and flips and so on.

[image]

Should I use OpenGL ES or Core Animation to implement this?

Comment: Try UIPageViewController it is a good start.

Comment: You can use Core Animation for this stuff. Try to use it.

Comment: Both the links in my answer could be found on the first page on google when you search for "ios page flip". You should _really_ have made more some effort before asking (downvoted)

Answer (score 2):

I really couldn't explain it any better than Mark Pospesel already did in his post [Anatomy of a page-flip animation](http://markpospesel.com/2012/05/23/anatomy-of-a-page-flip-animation/).

The solution is his solution uses Core Animation very effectively to do this and goes trough things like perspective and anti-aliasing. Finally he has [all the code on GitHub](https://github.com/mpospese/MPFoldTransition) under an attribution license. Though I strongly recommend you have a look at his post before jumping into the code as it explains the overall structure of the flip animation.

Answer (score 0):

I too am looking for something like this and there a few awesome things about the Paper implementation that the commenter and answerers of this question are overlooking.

1) Page flipping in paper is inertial. Got a 100 page book? Flip through dozens of pages at once with a strong swipe of the finger. Just like a real book. I haven't seen any free libraries that do that.
2) Watch the paper animation carefully. Looks to me like it was done in open gl. I don't think i've seen any core animation examples this fast and smooth. I could be wrong, and I'd love to be wrong.
3) Note how in Paper you can see beyond the edges of the current page so that you know how much of the book is on either side of the page you're currently on. Just like in a real book. This is subtle but critical.

If anyone has an idea of a library that takes on some of these things, do let me know.